# Heroku open gives a 404

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm deploying Rails on Heroku for the first time, so I accept I'm a bit of a newbie on this turf.

I installed the tool Heroku tool belt. Created a simple Rails application. Logged into Heroku. did..

```
heroku Create
```

And then pushed up the master

```
git push heroku master
```

Once the deployment is complete I tried

```
heroku open
```

I end up getting a 404. The app though runs fine on my local environment.

Comment: Do you have a `root` route set in your `config/routes.rb` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku does not provide a standard welcome page for Rails 4. So if you did not create one yourself  You will get a 404 page. This problem should not arise if your root to is properly set.

You can test this by creating a home controller with an index action, create the index. html.erb page and define root to: 'home#index'. Now heroku knows about the page and you will not receive a 404 error.

Getting started with heroku guide: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4